Complex analysis or real analysis books that have these special functions.
I saw an integral question that involved the digamma function, which I know nothing about, and I want to learn more about it, its properties, and other functions like the polylogarithm function and the hypergeometric function. So, I searched through all of my analysis books (Differential Equations, Real Analysis, Complex Analysis) to find any book that mentions the digamma function, but none of them do. The only books I have that contain the digamma function are problem books, which assume the reader is familiar with it and present hard problems involving it, making them not useful for me. The other type is special functions books, which don’t contain any proofs, so they are also not useful.
I know that I can search for the digamma function on Wikipedia, but I am more interested in finding an analysis book that contains the digamma function and its properties because such a book might have more interesting theories and functions that I know nothing about, like the polylogarithm function, the hypergeometric function, or even functions and theorems I didn't know existed.
If there are no analysis books with these functions and the other types of books (problem books, special functions books) cannot be relied on, then how did many people learn about these functions anyway? I don't think the people learnt these functions from articles so they must have used some analysis book to learn them.
So, I want to ask for analysis books (complex or real, but preferably complex analysis) that include the digamma function, the polylogarithm function, and the hypergeometric function, along with their properties and proofs. Additionally, I am looking for rigorous books that do not contain any real-world applications or physics.

Do you want a reference on specifically Polygamma functions or a reference on well-known special functions as a whole?

I understand your frustration. One of best references is Whittaker & Watson. A course of Modern Analysis.  Fourth Edition. In chapter 12.3 they discuss digamma function and polygamma but they simple called it $\displaystyle \psi(x)$ or $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x))$. Another good reference Erdélyi, Higher transcendental functions. Volume 1. Both books also discuss hypergeometric and other special functions.

You can find quite a bit of information on the Wolfram function site for the PolyGamma function, PolyLog function, and various Hypergeometric functions.

For polylogarithms $\operatorname{Li}{s}(x)$: Leonard Lewin. Polylogarithms and Associated Functions. It also discusses Clausen functions $\operatorname{Cl}{2}(x)$ and inverse tangent integral $\operatorname{Ti}_{2}(x)$

@Bertrand87 I can't find the book "Polylogarithms and Associated Function" can you give me a link to it?

@pie I don't have a link but you may find one in Library Genesis or similar sites

You can check the book https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123846549/mathematical-methods-for-physicists#book-description

Special functions and their applications by N.N Lebedev is a good reference

there is this ...
Andrews, George E.; Askey, Richard; Roy, Ranjan, Special functions, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 71. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xvi, 664 p. (1999). ZBL0920.33001.

that seems to be a very good book that have proofs and not just a collection of formulas.

The Functions of Mathematical Physics Harry Hochstadt Dover1986 is a fantastic book for the hypergeometric function.

The homepage NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions is the official (can be said)
document of any kind of special functions, descriptions, proofs, and references therein.
